# Internal error window shows when click on log navigator (⌘+7) in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When click on log navigator button(⌘+7) then shows the internal error window in my Xcode.Please go through the following screenshot.Please help me...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As we cannot prevent this issue,As clearly bug with xcode and   it is a logic error in `Xcode`, eventually `Apple` will get it fixed. `Quitting and Relaunching` will be the best option for us or Have you tried to `Uninstall` and `Install` it again. As we cannot debug the probelm will be good to [report it to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/wa/signIn)

Comment: A piece of aDVICE:iN REALLY BIG PROJECTS changing the compiler from gcc to llvm or vice-versa helps avoid crash.